# Fast way to remove a number only once from list of numbers in bash

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a file which is a list of numbers.

list_of_numbers

```
40426
140
26
3502
140
899320
```

and have another file which is a list of numbers to remove **only once**

numers_to_remove

```
140
3502
```

so the output file should be

```
40426
26
140
899320
```

Removing only once so 140 is remained as it appears twice in list_of_numbers.

Currently I'm doing

```
while read line ; do

    sed -i "0,/^$line$/s///" list_of_numbers

done < numbers_to_remove
```

is there any faster way to do in bash?
I will sort these number after this so the order of numbers are not important.

Comment: The ilst of numbers is in a file or is it an array?

Comment: @PS because OP wants to delete a single number once, and `140` appears twice in `list_of_numbers`

Comment: @KamilCuk It is a file, so in your answer it should be stored to array before?

Comment: If it's in a file, you can just `cat FILE` instead of `printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store all numbers to delete in an array.
After processing the first file (`FNR==NR`), continue with second file.
When a value is found in the remove array, delete it from the array and look at the next row.
When a value is not in the array print it.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}
     $0 in a{delete a[$0];next}
     {print}' numbers_to_remove list_of_numbers
```

Comment: Do we need "<" in the last line? I think it works without.

Comment: Deleted the typo `<`, you don't need it. I tested it with `<(some_command)` generating a testfile.

Comment: I see, now it works even with larger file. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One `sed` should be faster them many:

```
list_of_numbers=(
    40426 140 26
    3502 140 899320
)

numbers_to_remove=(
    140 3502
)

printf "%s\n" "${list_of_numbers[@]}" |
sed "$(printf '0,/^%d$/s///\n' "${numbers_to_remove[@]}")/^$/d"
```

will output:

```
40426
26
140
899320
```

- `printf` repeats it's format string for arguments. So `printf "A %d" 1 2` will output `A 1A 2`.
- first We output list of numbers on separate newlines
- then we format `sed` argument to be `0,/^<number here>$/s///<newline>` for each number in the list of numbers to remove. The newline is used to separate `sed` commands.
- Last `sed` command is to remove empty lines, ie. `/^$/d` - delete lines which has nothing.

Answer (score 0):

With awk - This does expect presorted records. Order doesn't matter as long as both files use the same ordering scheme.

```
awk '
  BEGIN{ getline skipnum < "numbers_to_remove"; old=""; }
  { if ( $0 == skipnum && old != skipnum ) {
       old = skipnum;
       getline skipnum < "a";
       next;
    } else print;
  }
' list_of_numbers
```

`BEGIN` prereads a line from the list to skip.
On each record, if skipnum is set and matches the current line,
- then try to read the next skipnum - fail should leave it empty.
- `next` skips printing that record.
else print the current record.

It's a fast, single read through each file.

If you don't want to presort them, then use an associative array and delete each element as found.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    while (getline skipnum < "numbers_to_remove") { skips[skipnum] = 1; }
  }
  { if ( $0 in skips ) {
       delete skips[$0];
       next;
    } else print;
  }
' list_of_numbers
```

Comment: Hi thanks. The first one works when I use "sort -n" but not "sort -rn", it prints only 899320, 40426, 26. Does it have to be small to big?

Comment: Did you sort both files with thew same sort arguments?

Comment: Yes I used "cat list_of_numbers | sort -rn > list_of_numbers_s" for both. when I change the option just -n then it works and outputs 4 numbers.

Comment: I'm getting the same result, and I confess that at first glance I don't know why. It works with or without numeric sorting, fails with either in reverse order... The second one works in any case, but I'm surprised the reverse ordering is causing a problem for the first example.  Hopefully one of the old `awk` pros will explain it for us. I never in 25 years of command-line IT work used `awk` before this year, lol. I'd've written it in `perl`, likely using the second logic unless the files are really big and you *really* need fast processing. (Sorts are slow pre-work for big files.)

Comment: The second one works but yes I'll "sort -rn" later anyway so wanted to sort in this step with your first way. Maybe I should write in Perl as you advise if it requires speed, just bash was easier to manipulate files. Thank you for help anyway :)

Comment: We could do it in bash with the same logic (either one), but `read` is notoriously slow over large files because it has to read a character at a time instead of buffering. Great if that's what you need to do anyway, but this second logic (which is basically what Walter A did) is generally the same as I'd write in `perl`. Let us know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Apparently a failed `getline` read doesn't clear the existing value. I added some logic. Try that.